# Webpack server открывается, но не обновляется

Tags: javascript, консоль, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Поставил вебпак, запускаю дев сервер, сервер открывается, но не обновляется и в консоль выкидывает много ошибок.

В чём ошибки кода? Нужно, чтобы обновлятся без сохранения и не вываливал ерроры.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu07H.png)
Прикрепляю скрины и код.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 9000,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решил.

Она заключалась в том, что в имени моей папки был элемент "#"